# Can we get weakly convergence from the above Glivenko-Cantelli theorem?

Tags: probability, analysis

I am reading this result:
[image]

Here the empirical distribution function $F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum I(X_i\le x)$ and $\mu_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum\delta_{X_i}$.

Question: If I want to prove that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ weakly. Can we get this conclusion from the above Glivenko-Cantelli theorem?

---

Why do we need almost surely $F_n(\cdot)(\omega)\to F$ uniformly on $R$ rather than
$$
\mbox{ almost surely } F_n(x)(\omega)\to F
$$
for each $x\in R$ by SLLN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can since GC implies pointwise convergence of the empirical measures to the limiting measure..

Uniform convergence is a stronger condition than normal convergence:

Uniform Convergence $\implies$ Pointwise Convergence

Therefore $F_n(\cdot)(\omega)\to F$ uniformly a.s $ \implies F_n(x)(\omega)\to F$ for each $x\in R$ a.s.

Comment: And therefore the measures converge weakly, by the characterization of weak convergence via distribution functions.

Comment: No, that is not my question. I want to ask how to prove can we prove that $\mu_n $ converges to $\mu$  weakly from that theorem?

Comment: See @Alexisz comment —

Comment: So, in summary:

Glivenko-Cantelli <-> uniform convergence a.s. -> pointwise convergence a.s. -> weak convergence a.s.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures

Comment: @Hermi this ^^^

Comment: @Bey Yes, so pointwise convergence a.s. is enough, right? And $\mu_n\to \mu$ pointwise a.s. is just by the Strong law of large number? Therefore, $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly.

Comment: So the logic is that by SLLN, we have $\mu_n\to \mu$ a.s. Hence, $\mu_n\to \mu$ weakly.

Comment: @Hermi correct!